# Linkedin identity Verification

Tags: security, linkedin-api, verification

i am facing a problem, the problem is while i am trying to login my linkedin account, i put the email and the password, then security verification page popups, then i verify it by doing some CAPTCHA, then he ask me to enter my phone number, i did hit the submit button but the problem is it says "Session invalid or expired".Each time it happens and i can't login my account, What should i do? [Thats the error message while i'm trying to submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apG2v.png)

I an trying to login my account but it didn't work

Comment: try to clear your browser history, or try using a new browser , if any VPN is turned on then turn it off

Answer (score 0):

Same is the issue with me i have tried different VPN and also different devices/browsers, but these all still not worked for me, any one having some helpful idea please must share
Regards

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me as well. LinkedIn's security processes are poorly structured - you will find that obstruction rather than security is their fallback. You have likely had your account blocked. Why? Who knows? LinkedIn may reveal that to you (but not always). First you have to login. Which is where we all started...

You can wait a day or so to see whether they re-enable the account. Alternatively, try the one-time login. You will still be blocked but you are offered the opportunity to send a copy of your government ID to them. Could take a couple of weeks to get back to you depending on how many staff are left there. Also, be aware that they may reject your first ID offering and demand some other document.

Let us know if you are back in and what that process was.